# Jenkins timeout/abort exception

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a Jenkins pipeline script that requests approval from the user after all the preparatory steps are complete, before it actually applies the changes.

We want to add a timeout to this step, so that if there is no input from the user then the build is aborted, and are currently working on using this kind of method:

```
    try {
      timeout(time: 30, unit: 'SECONDS') {
        userInput = input("Apply changes?")
      }
    } catch(err) {
      def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()

      if (user.toString == 'SYSTEM') {  // if it's system it's a timeout
        didTimeout = true
        echo "Build timed out at approval step"
      } else if (userInput == false) {  // if not and input is false it's the user
        echo "Build aborted by: [${user}]"
      }
    }
```

This code is based on examples found here: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226554067-Pipeline-How-to-add-an-input-step-with-timeout-that-continues-if-timeout-is-reached-using-a-default-value and other places online, but I really dislike catching *all* errors then working out what's caused the exception using `err.getCauses()[0].getUser()`. I'd rather explicitly `catch(TimeoutException)` or something like that.

So my question is, what are the actual exceptions that would be thrown by either the approval step timing out or the userInput being false? I haven't been able to find anything in the docs or Jenkins codebase so far about this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The exception class they are referring to is `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException`.

Cannot believe that this is an example provided by CloudBeeds.

Most (or probably all?) other exceptions won't even have the `getCauses()` method which of course would throw another exception then from within the catch block.

Furthermore as you already mentioned it is not a good idea to just catch all exceptions.

Edit:
By the way: Scrolling further down that post - in the comments - there you'll find an example catching a `FlowInterruptedException`.

Comment: Unfortunately "FlowInterruptedException" has multiple causes: User Cancel, Milestone, or Timeout. There are probably others, too.  There is an "isActualInterruption()" to determine if it's user created.

Comment: In my testing, isActualInterruption doesn't distinguish between Abort and timeout either. You'd need to look at `getCauses()` for more details.

Comment: Followup to my prior comment: `getCauses()` and `isActualInterruption()` are both restricted and cannot be used in a groovy sandbox. Bad design IMHO.  It's just not practical to make random exemptions to allow code to work.

Answer (score 2):

Rather old topic, but it helped me, and I've done some more research on it.

As I figured out, `FlowInterruptedException`'s `getCauses()[0]` has `.getUser()` only when class of `getCauses()[0]` is `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.Rejection`. It is so only when timeout occured while input was active. But, if timeout occured not in input, `getCause()[0]` will contain object of another class: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.TimeoutStepExecution$ExceededTimeout` (directly mentioning timeout).

So, I end up with this:

```
def is_interrupted_by_timeout(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException e, Boolean throw_again=true) {
    // if cause is not determined, re-throw exception
    try {
        def cause = e.getCauses()[0]
        def cause_class = cause.getClass()
        //echo("cause ${cause} class: ${cause_class}")
        if( cause_class == org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.TimeoutStepExecution$ExceededTimeout ) {
            // strong detection
            return true
        } else if( cause_class == org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.Rejection ) {
            // indirect detection
            def user = cause.getUser()
            if( user.toString().equals('SYSTEM') ) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    } catch(org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException e_access) {
        // here, we may deal with situation when restricted methods are not approved:
        // show message and Jengins' admin will copy/paste and execute them only once per Jenkins installation.
        error('''
            To run this job, Jenkins admin needs to approve some Java methods.
            There are two possible ways to do this:

            1. (better) run this code in Jenkins Console (URL: /script):

            import org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval;
            def scriptApproval = ScriptApproval.get()
            scriptApproval.approveSignature('method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException getCauses')
            scriptApproval.approveSignature('method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.Rejection getUser')
            scriptApproval.save()
            '''.stripIndent())
        return null
    }
    if( throw_again ) {
        throw e
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

And now, you may catch it with something like this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException err) {
    if( is_interrupted_by_timeout(err) ) {
        echo('It is timeout!')
    }
}
```

P.S. I agree, this is bad Jenkins design.