# "X error - bad window" issue in Jenkins GUI tests

Tags: jenkins, redhat, xserver

As soon as we have code submission for our project, our Jenkins task which contains GUI tests will be triggered to run automatically. It was recently discovered that there was a stuck issue with low probability while running the tests, resulting in a test timeout (timeout of 120 minutes I set) causing Jenkins to end the task.

Some error messages related to "X error-Bad Window" were found in the test log as follows:

X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)

Major opcode of failed request:  25 (X_SendEvent)

Resource id in failed request:  0x5c00011

Serial number of failed request:  9

Current serial number in output stream:  10

57417: INFO: received signal SIGTERM by PID 50158

57930: INFO: received signal SIGTERM by PID 50158

57459: INFO: received signal SIGTERM by PID 50158

57510: INFO: received signal SIGTERM by PID 50158

I tried to find out the reason by the process ids, However, these processes had been killed, and it was difficult to tell from the only log information.

I also tried to grab some system logs and our test logs in Jenkins timout (see documentation:[Jenkins timeout/abort exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260440/jenkins-timeout-abort-exception)),
Unfortunately, the captured log shows that our product was killed when the log was captured.

Who knows how to get Jenkins to grab useful information before ending tasks/killing processes in a timeout?
Or can you offer some other ideas?

A few points to note:

1. This problem has a low probability, about 1%
2. Jenkins timeout cannot be canceled due to project particularities
3. Due to the particularity of the project, it is not allowed to add excessive debugging information to the test
4. The stuck test is not fixed

Thank you guys!